# Php foreach limits array show

Tags: php, foreach

Hey i have a problem when i want add limits shows arrays on foreach  `&& ++$i > 4) break;`  then script working not currently then shows all playlistId and after shows videoId but i want only videoId shows `echo $item->id->videoId;` please help i try 3hours to fix it.

```
    $i = 0;
    foreach($videoList->items as $item){
        if(isset($item->id->videoId) && $videoLike[$item->id->videoId]->viewCount && ++$i > 4) break; {     
            echo $item->id->videoId;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please take a breath and read back your question. You are not showing us enough code or describing your issue very well. Please try editing you question into better shape

Comment: It would also be useful to see the JSON that you are processing

Comment: Already answerd but thanks to try help too

Comment: Thats not really the point. If another person has similair issues they also will not be able to understand your question and therefore will miss the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to change your conditions slightly.  Instead of adding the condition `++$i > 4` to your main `if()`, I think it should be nested inside the `if()`.  Nesting this test will mean it won't count the items that you don't display...

```
$i = 0;
foreach($videoList->items as $item){
    if(isset($item->id->videoId) && $videoLike[$item->id->videoId]->viewCount ) {     
        echo $item->id->videoId;
        if ( ++$i > 4) {
           break; 
        }
    }
}
```